# React component renders 2 time

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in React JS

I have an issue with my app that a component renders 2 times. I have the components `Popup` and `MultipleCombobox`. But `MultiCombobox` is always rendered 2 times.

Popup.js

```js
const commandModal = useMemo(() =>
      {
        var formBody = columns.map((column, index) =>
        {
          if (!column.showOnlyGrid)
          {
            if (!column.render)
            {
              if (column.type === FieldType.TEXT)
              {
                return (
                  <React.Fragment key={column.field}>
                    <CFormLabel key={`${column.field}-label`} className='required'>{column.text}</CFormLabel>
                    <div className='mb-3' key={`${column.field}-input`}>
                      <CFormInput disabled={disabled} key={`${column.field}-form-input`}
                        type='text'
                        value={popupSlice.data[column.field] || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => dispatch(setProperty({
                          name: column.field,
                          value: e.target.value
                        }))}
                        pattern='^\S.*$'
                        required
                        feedbackInvalid={'Please enter ' + column.text}
                        placeholder={'Enter ' + column.text} />
                    </div>
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              }
              else
              {
                return (
                  <div className='mb-3' key={`${column.field}-input`}>
                    <CFormCheck key={index}
                      disabled={disabled}
                      id={column.field}
                      label={column.text}
                      checked={popupSlice.data[column.field]}
                      onChange={(e) => dispatch(setProperty({
                        name: column.field,
                        value: e.target.checked
                      }))} />
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }
            else
            {
              if (column.render.type === FieldType.SELECT && column.render.sourceType === SourceType.SERVER)
              {
                return (
                  <React.Fragment key={column.field}>
                    <CFormLabel key={`${column.field}-label`} className='required'>{column.text}</CFormLabel>
                    <div className='mb-3' key={`${column.field}-input`}>
                      <MultiCombobox key={column.field} url={column.render.url}
                        onChange={(select) => dispatch(setProperty({
                          name: column.field,
                          value: select.map(item => item.value)
                        }))}
                        selectedValue={popupSlice.data[column.field]}
                        isValid={popupSlice.data[column.field] && popupSlice.data[column.field].length > 0 ? true : false}
                        validate={popupSlice.configuration.validate}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              }              
            }
          }
          return null;
        });
    
        return formBody;
      }, [columns, popupSlice, dispatch, handleSubmit]);
```

MultiCombobox.js

```js
function MultiCombobox(props)
{

  console.log('Init multiCombobox');


  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default MultiCombobox;
```

I have also tried removing `StrictMode`.

Comment: Hello, is your problem in localhost only ? Do you have [react strict mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the MultiCombobox component is rendered twice because it is included twice in the useMemo commandModal function.

fix create new function

```
const Test = (props) => {
   const { column } = props;
  return (
    column.render.type === FieldType.SELECT &&
    column.render.sourceType === SourceType.SERVER
  );
}
```

MultiCombobox.js

```
function MultiCombobox(props)
{

  console.log('Init multiCombobox');

if(!Test(props){return null})
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default MultiCombobox;
```